# Laravel: How the best way for redirect a default laravel user to admin page if user is admin or to user page if user is not admin?

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect, conditional-statements, admin

The User model has an isAdmin() function to check if the user is an administrator. What to do next?

Comment: The form login is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use default laravel `LoginController` located under `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`.

In that controller you can override `authenticated` method that is injected from `AuthenticatesUsers` trait, by simply adding that method in `LoginController`:

```
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $user
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->isAdmin()) {
        return redirect(route('admin-dashboard')); 
       //redirect to desired place since user is admin.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practique is whit roles, and you add role on your Routes::middleware,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'roles:admin']], function () {
//Your routes
});
```

Kernel.php

```
 'roles' => Middleware\CheckRole::class,
```

Create middleware

```
   namespace App\Http\Middleware;

  use Closure;

  class CheckRole
   {
     public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$role)
     {
    if ($request->user()->hasAnyRole($role)) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect(route('hour'));
   }

    }
```

create function on User model

```
public function authorizeRole($role)
{
    if ($this->hasAnyRole($role)) {
        return true;
    }
    return abort(401, 'Unauthorized.');
}
 public function hasAnyRole($roles)
{
    if (is_array($roles)) {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function hasRole($role)
{
    if ($this->role()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role')->withDefault();
}
```

And Role model

```
<?php

   namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class Role extends Model
    {
        public function user()
       {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
     }
    }
```

Is more code, but best way for this action